# Importing js (es6) files into typescript parent dependencies with non conventional extension `*.es6` fails? ts(2307)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

We are adding typescript to our project which for legacy and migration purposes overtime has had ***.es6 files for source es6 modules** vs ***.js (which are loose generated files and bundles)**.

What i have found in typescript is i can import these exact files if they are .js / .ts, i would prefer not to have to rename and change all build tooling and etc from .es6 to .js for all files in the repo. Im assuming there should be a way to say **treat extension of "es6" as a "js" non-ts file**

*p.s. Also if this is maybe an IDE issue (but ther error is coming direct from TS), my IDE is VSCode*

Example:

```
// asbstracted models
import { Model } from "./model.es6"; // js (because ext, typescript intellisense error)

// resources
import { http } from '../utils/http.es6'; // js (because ext, typescript intellisense error)
import { Rando } from '../utils/rando'; // ts (ok)
import { Rando2 } from '../utils/rando2.js'; // js (ok)


...
```

I tried adding all sort of things to tsconfig.json. Babel / webpack can compile the bundle fine, but the tsconfig in vscode is throwing. The lint error is:

```
Cannot find module '../utils/http.es6' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": [
    "js_es6/**/*.ts",
    "js_es6/**/*.es6",
  ],
  "types": ["./types/index.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@js_es6/*": ["js_es6/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to typescript configuration but is it flexible enough to allow variable file extensions for js, as up into now build tooling and js is more or less extension agnostic.

image for additional reference:
[image]

Comment: You're _way_ better off fixing your filenames instead of perpetuating this hack. If it's a lot, automate it.

Comment: i will over time move everything to ts but for now i just want to do it incrementally, im wondering if there is a configuration that im missing as it doesnt seem like it would be that complex if extension is specified to map

Comment: Looks like [the `include` option of *tsconfig*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) should handle this

Comment: But see also [this extensive discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10939)

Comment: yup i did try to explicitly include the extension glob'd ill add it to the main thread my tsconfig.json. And yes did see that proposal (re:github thread), but didnt seem to be implemented in capacity, but exactly what would be nice.